# How to show description for widget & it's parameters in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

I'm developing a flutter package wherein I want to add docs for widget's parameters like this,

[image]

**I'm referring to the description of the widget and it's parameters!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can comment using the `///`. For more information, reference the [Effective Dart: Documentation#doc-comments](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation#doc-comments).

```dart
/// This function is ~~~
///
/// The [num] must be non-null ~~
void simpleFunction(int num) {

}
```

Comment: Tried it before, but this time with more clarity and It works. Thanks :)